Integrating Cloudflare Services with Azure DNS Management
I have a domain, abc.com, and all its DNS records are managed on Azure. I would like to utilize Cloudflare's services, but I want to keep DNS management on Azure.
I want requests directed to the A and www records on Azure to pass through Cloudflare's services, such as WAF, CDN, etc. How can I achieve this?
